# How to get discord bot to mention me and the person i mention in the command

Tags: python, discord

example of what I mean (" +slap @examplename") the bot would then put in chat "@me slapped @examplename" I just can't seem to get it to work.

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

bot = Bot(command_prefix='+')

bot.command()
async def slap(self, member : discord.Member):
        """<member>: Be careful with this one."""
        await self.bot.say("*slaps {0} around a bit with a large, girthy trout*".format(member))


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
        print ("------------------------------------")
        print ("Bot Name: " + bot.user.name)
        print ("Bot ID: " + bot.user.id)
        print ("Discord Version: " + discord.__version__)
        print ("------------------------------------")
        await bot.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='Created By Pluto'))


bot.run('')
```

Answer (score 2):

I've removed `self`, as you don't appear to be using cogs:

```
bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def slap(member: discord.Member):
        """<member>: Be careful with this one."""
        await bot.say("{} slaps {}".format(ctx.message.author.mention, member.mention))
```

`Member` objects (including `message.author`) have a `mention` attribute that allows you to mention them easily.